# How to measure scroll-able cards?

Tags: analytics, measuring, user-tracking

We are creating a news app, which provides short news. For this, we have used google's material cards which are scroll-able and tabs for categories. Our main concern is how to track these cards properly? since everything gets tracked if you scroll too fast.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand where you're coming from. How would you get multiple page views? In Google Analytics?

Comment: @DanielSlowacek I mean if you scroll too fast even those articles you don't read will be counted in PVS.

Comment: This is true, but that's a tracking issue then. For example facebook videos generate 1 view only after they've been played for a certain amount of time (3-5 seconds afaik). You just need to define this threshold and then keep it in mind when analyzing the data. I don't really understand how this challenge is related to Usability though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the image below and imagine articles are in *cards* layout:

[image]

Now, after seeing this page, did you read all articles and news in it? Or just a snippet of the article with maybe a photo?

Translating to your app, what you have is called a [*coplanar*](https://material.google.com/components/cards.html#cards-usage)

> A card collection is coplanar, or a layout of cards on the same plane.

So it's easy to see a coplanar is just a container, and you want to track *cards*, not *coplanars*

Well, there goes your answer: **you track the container or coplanar for all cards** like in any web page and **you track cards only if the user chose to click on any of them**, therefore effectively going to a new tracked page or an expanded view of the card (in this case, you can track the expand button)